# Windows 7 PC Searching

Tags: windows-7

When I perform searches on my works PC running windows7 is there a way to show where the search is and what it is searching. I regularly have to search large data areas (10-20Tb) for specific information and it can take a few days to complete but during the search I have no way of knowing or seeing where the search is. Can you display the folder / path somewhere to show how the search is progressing?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a file manager (like the well known Total Commander or Multi Commander). Any decent file manager (free) will be able to display the current folders and sub-folders the search is done it.

Comment: Removed your opinionated comments and links which may or may not be useful (I'm sure OP can use Google). Now it's +1 from me